# IIS virtual folder mime types

Tags: iis, mime-type

Consider following scenario. I have physical folder with mp3 files. I want these files to be served with `application/octet-stream` mime when accessed via http://example.com/dl/foo.mp3 and with `audio/mpeg` when accessed via http://example.com/audio/foo.mp3. So I create two virtual folders (`audio` and `dl`) in IIS Site both pointing to same physical folder. Turns out they share mime-type settings, i.e. when I change mime-type for one virtual folder it changes for another. I have even tried to make 2 completely different sites for this purpose but to no avail. How do I make it right?